How to manage NuGet-packages in Visual Studio Code?
I want to be able to see which NuGet-packages in my .NET-solution (with multiple projects) are up-to-date and which aren't. And when they are not up-to-date, I want to select them and update them, multiple at the same time, like in Visual Studio, in the NuGet Package Manager (right-click on Solution -> Manage NuGet packages for solution). I also want to see if there is more than one version of a package in use in different projects of the solution.
How can I manage this in VSCode or do I have to use Visual Studio for this?
I've tried multiple plugins for VS Code, but none of them showed which packages in my solution are outdated and offered a simple solution to updating a few of them, solution-wide.
